# How to send data to a Soap service?

Tags: java, android, soap, android-ksoap2

The `Soap service` expects the following operation:

```
<wsdl:operation name="UploadFile">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://abcdotcom/IDocUpload/UploadFile" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="FileInfo">
<soap:header message="tns:FileInfo_Headers" part="Name" use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:FileInfo_Headers" part="Length" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="DownloadRequest">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I am using `ksoap2 library`. I am not able to figure out how to send data to the service?
I am trying with

```
request.addProperty("FileInfo", "123");
```

but its just giving me `null` response. I am expecting an `error` at least. Please help.

Comment: please provide what error your getting?

Comment: I am just getting a null result. No response at all.

Comment: @Ali_Waris if you are getting null response then are you sure you are sending a valid request ?. Did you debugged you code ?

Answer (score 4):

Sample soap request in android (method:FetchUserDetails)

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "FetchUserDetails");
request.addProperty("key", value);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ServiceURL);
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/FetchUserDetails", envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            int count = response.getPropertyCount();
            if (count > 0) {
             //handel the response
             SoapObject results = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
           }
       }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("service", e.getMessage());
      }
```

Comment: When i evaluate envelope.getResponse(), it shows me null everytime.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to use addProperty() to support the kind of input expected by the Soap service that I shared above.